# jQuery $.param() fails to serialize multiple <select> element

Tags: jquery

Running into a bit of a head scratcher passing a jQuery object to an `$.ajax()` request as data.  Apparently `$.ajax()` processes objects into a query string using `$.param()`, but `$.param()` fails to properly serialize data from a multiple select element.  Instead it sends only the first value.

The [docs for `$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) state:

> Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a
>   jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request.
>   In case a jQuery object is passed, it should contain input elements
>   with name/value properties.

For this, `serialize()` works just fine but `$.param()` fails. **Is this a bug with `$.param()` or am I missing something here?**

Please, I am *not looking for a solution*.  As I have said, I can simply use `serialize()` as a workaround before passing the data to `$.ajax()`.  The question I am asking is about the proper use of `$.param()` and whether or not this is, in fact, a bug.

See example below illustrating the difference in results.  Select multiple options to see the difference.

**UPDATE:**  I added some text inputs to the demo below with the name `text[]` as these should be encoded into an array the same as the multiple select.  Turns out `$.param()` deals with these just fine - so the problem seems to be specifically related to the select.

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  var param_query = $.param($('select, input'));
  var serialize_query = $('select, input').serialize();
  $('#param').html(param_query);
  $('#serialize').html(serialize_query);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#output,
i {
  color: blue;
}
span {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="5" multiple name="colors[]">
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="gold">gold</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
  <option value="White">white</option>
</select><br />
<input placeholder="Enter some text here..." name="text[]" /><br />
<input placeholder="Enter some text here..." name="text[]" /><br />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div><b>QUERY STRING RESULTS:</b>
  <br />
  <i>$.param()</i>: <span id="param"></span>
  <br />
  <i>serialize()</i>: <span id="serialize"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. The documentation doesn't mention anything about multi-select. It's able to generate multiple parameters for an array, so it seems like it should do the same thing for a multi-select.

Comment: You might try posting this at forum.jquery.com, see what they have to say about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is not a bug, that's the standard behavior.**

Instead of selecting the whole `select`, you should inform which `selected` `option`s you want; `$.param()` requires an array to work properly. In the snippet I inform an array as a parameter to produce the same result as `serialize` does (it seems like it gets the element and transforms it into an array, because it knows a `select` can be transformed into one).

As nicely informed by [J Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026459/travis-j) in the comments

> `param` simply does `$obj.each(function(){ this.value })` and
>   `this.value` only gets the first selection in a multiple select

For that reason `$.param()` is not able to transform any HTML element into a proper array and then serialize it.

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  var selectedItemsArray = $('select').find(':selected').map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
              }).get();
  
  var selectedItems =   $('select').find(':selected')  ;
  
  var param_query_Array = $.param({colors: selectedItemsArray});
  
  var param_query_Selected = $.param( selectedItems);
  
  var serialize_query = $('select').serialize();
  $('#param').html(param_query_Array);
  $('#paramSelected').html(param_query_Selected);
  $('#serialize').html(serialize_query);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#output,
i {
  color: blue;
}
span {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="5" multiple name="colors[]">
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="gold">gold</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
  <option value="White">white</option>
</select>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div><b>QUERY STRING RESULTS:</b>
  <br />
  <i>$.param()</i>: <span id="param"></span>
   <br />
  <i>$.param($('select').find(':selected')</i>: <span id="paramSelected"></span>
  <br />
  <i>serialize()</i>: <span id="serialize"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it, regardless of if the behavior is standard or a bug. The main issue is that internally param will simply use `$obj.each(function(){ this.value })` and `this.value` only gets the first selection in a multiple select element. Passing the set of options (where each option's this.value is then properly represented) will allow $.param to populate the query string. See more here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js , search for *.param* to find the function definition.

Comment: @TravisJ I updated the answer with your information, if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: To note though, it *may* be a bug as it does not properly cover all use cases and requires at least a little workaround.

Comment: @TravisJ The way I see it it's not a bug; the problem with the code in the question is that he is selecting the whole `select` instead of the selected options. The behavior gets closer to the expected result if the usage was like this: 
 `var param_query_Selected = $.param( $('select').find(':selected'));`

Comment: @ClayKaboom - thanks for your insights.  based on the description in the docs it seems like a bug to me, but based on the actual code used by jquery, it is behaving correctly.  imo,either the code or the docs are deficient.